# [python / matplolib ]Does fill the specified color with pcolormesh?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I have a data in textfile. 
I want to load data and will draw the basemap and fill the color with pcolormesh function.
But pcolormesh fill color automatically.
Do you know a specific value can be displayed in a particular color?

For example, All values fill automatically color and '0' value fill the black.
Is it possible?

Help me!

Comment: See [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/quadmesh_demo.html). Note `ax.set_axis_bgcolor("#bdb76b")` as an example of the backfill color.

Comment: thank you! i sovled it!!